# How get the value of multiple checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieve some data from a database, put it into a table view

```
if (isset($_POST['user_id'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['user_id'] as $value) {
                $user = User::find($value);
                $id = Some::create([
                            'user_id'                   => $user->id,
                            'user_email'                => $user->email,
                            'user_name'                 => $user->name,
                            'location'                  => $user->location,
                            'user_phone'                => $user->phone,
                            'created_at'                => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(3),
                            ]);
                          $id->update(['created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(3)]);
                          $id->created_at =  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(3);
                          $id->save();
                    if ($id)
                    {
                        // delete user from PH table
                        $deleteUser = ProvideHelp::where('user_id', $id->user_id)->delete();
                        if ($deleteUser) {
                            return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Your Addition was successful');
                        }

                    }
            }
        }

        return redirect('home')->with('error', 'Inter Error Please try again Later');
```

The loop only works for the first data and rest doesn't work. I want to use the values for each loop to query the database. Only the first query works - the second or third do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think. There's only one userid sent to the php script, and for that reason, it'll loop only ONCE.

I think you're requesting for the userid once. You will need a loop to read the value of multiple checkboxes. I'll suggest you add an index to the name of each chexkboxes, to be able to access it through a php loop.

Comment: there more than one userid and it index as `userid[]`

Comment: there more than one userid and it index as `userid[]`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you need to place a "[]" after the name values of your checkboxes so they look like this in your HTML:

`name='user_id[]'`

otherwise, when you pass the checkbox values to your PHP it will only pass the first value.